# Why is the navigation bar so tall

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode14

Im running Xcode 14 beta 6 and this page is a link from my home page and the nav bar is stacking like there is two.

If you don't understand here's some images [image]
[image]

and here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProductsLink: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    
    var btnBack : some View { Button(action: {
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }) {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.backward.circle")
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .foregroundColor(Color("LaunchText"))
        }
    }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Products(text: "All Products")
            .navigationBarItems(leading: btnBack)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
    }
}


struct ProductsLink_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProductsLink()
        
    }
}
```

contentview:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 1
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    }
    var body: some View {
        
        TabView(selection: $selection {
            Home()
            .tabItem { Label("Home", systemImage: "house.fill") }.tag(1)
            About()
            .tabItem { Label("About", systemImage: "person.crop.circle") }.tag(2)
            Products()
            .tabItem { Label("Products", systemImage: "bag.fill") }.tag(3)
            Gallery()
            .tabItem { Label("Gallery", systemImage: "photo.on.rectangle") }.tag(4)
            Contact()
            .tabItem { Label("Contact", systemImage: "phone.bubble.left.fill") }.tag(5)
            
            
        }
        .accentColor(Color("Green Power Logo Colour"))
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

products:

```
struct Products: View {
    var text = "Products"
    var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                ScrollView {
                AllProductCards
                    NavigationLink(destination: ContactForm()) {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Intrested. Contact Form \(Image(systemName: "arrow.forward.circle"))")
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            } .frame(width: 250 ,height: 50)
                                .background(Color("Dark Green"))
                                .cornerRadius(7)
                        }
                    Footer()
            }
                .navigationTitle(text)
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        
    }
}

struct Products_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Products()
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one thing, in the ContentView, you are referencing the Products view. If look into the Products view, there is an AllProductCards reference to (I guess) another view. I don't know what's in the view. My assumption would be, it is a List/VStack with NavigationLinks to the ProductsLinks. The ProductsLinks itself are referencing to Products. Is that correct, or what is AllProductsLinks doing? If my assumption is correct, you are looping the products. Since the NavigationView() is part of the Products, that causes a nested NavigationView() into another NavigationView()

I'd think about the looping situation and change that.
For now and here it is "fixed" if you pull out the NavigationView(). You would have to moved the NavigationView() from the Products view into the ContentView like below. So even if the Products view is looped, you have just one NavigationView().
Again, I implemented the AllProductCards according to my assumption.

### The updated ContentView (Products nested into NavigationView()):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 1
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    }
    var body: some View {
        
        TabView(selection: $selection {
            Home()
            .tabItem { Label("Home", systemImage: "house.fill") }.tag(1)
            About()
            .tabItem { Label("About", systemImage: "person.crop.circle") }.tag(2)
            NavigationView {
                Products()
            }
            .tabItem { Label("Products", systemImage: "bag.fill") }.tag(3)
            Gallery()
            .tabItem { Label("Gallery", systemImage: "photo.on.rectangle") }.tag(4)
            Contact()
            .tabItem { Label("Contact", systemImage: "phone.bubble.left.fill") }.tag(5)
            
            
        }
        .accentColor(Color("Green Power Logo Colour"))
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

### The updated Products view (removed NavigationView()):

```
struct Products: View {
    var text = "Products"
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            AllProductCards()
            NavigationLink(destination: ContactForm()) {
                HStack {
                    Text("Intrested. Contact Form \(Image(systemName: "arrow.forward.circle"))")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                } .frame(width: 250 ,height: 50)
                    .background(Color("Dark Green"))
                    .cornerRadius(7)
            }
            Footer()
        }
        .navigationTitle(text)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but This didn't work.

Comment: Can you please share your PrdouctsView as well as your ContentView (or wherever you set up the NavigationView)? I'd like to reproduce it.

Comment: I am sorry, I just saw in your first picture the .inline behavior. It would be great to have more details about the entire app (as requested in my last comment).

Comment: @Sebasitian Fox I added them

Comment: @Ash, I updated my answer according to your updated code. Within the `Products` view, the `AllProductsCards` item/view is missing, but I assume it is handling the `ProductsLink` view(s) which open(s) the 'Products' view **again** and that's why it is causing a loop of showing the `Products` view (at least multiple times/twice). Since the `NavigationView()` is part of Products, you'll have (multiple) nested NavigationViews. That (could) cause this error.